# Hiding declaration of type synonym in Haddock

Tags: haskell, haddock

I'm writing a library, and in it I have defined and exported some (very convoluted) type synonym `T`.

```
-- | A type
type T a b i o = ReaderT (WriterT i a X) (WriterT i b o)
```

Internal to the library, the type makes sense. To a user, however, it is unecessary and confusing. For that reason, I would prefer to hide the actual declaration of the type in the Haddock page.

I.E., I would prefer the Haddock page look like this...

```
type T a b i o
    A type
```

... rather than this.

```
type T a b i o = ReaderT (WriterT i a X) (WriterT i b o)
    A type
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users really don't need to know what's under the hood, you should use a `newtype` and not export the constructor. `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` can help ease the pain of this approach. If some of your users may want to peek behind the curtain, you can expose the `newtype` constructor from a base module but hide it from the main module. Type synonyms are a very weak tool for abstraction in general. The `lens` library uses them to good effect, to allow packages to define lenses without depending on `lens`, but that's a bit of an oddball.

I don't think there's any way to tell Haddock to hide what a type synonym means. That doesn't, however, mean you can't do what you want.

Cabal defines the `__HADDOCK_VERSION__` CPP macro when documentation is being built. If you're so inclined, you can detect this and replace the type synonym with a `newtype`. This wouldn't compile, of course, but I don't think it should cause Haddock any trouble. I don't think this is at all wise, though.

Comment: I had considered this, and in the long run it may be the route I choose to take with the library. However, I am still interested, largely out of curiosity, if what I asked about is possible. If you include an answer to that question in your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Kwarrtz, I've added information on how to detect a documentation build.